# Is there a "\nocolumnbreak" analog to \nopagebreak?

Tags: page-breaking, two-column

If I want to prevent latex from putting two (short) paragraphs on different columns, is there something similar to `\nopagebreak` that will let me do this?

Comment: AFAIK columns are handled like different pages and so `\nopagebreak` should do what you want.

Comment: @Martin I couldn't get `\nopagebreak` to work, but maybe I just didn't insist on it enough.

Comment: You could place the paragraphs into a `{minipage}{\columnwidth}` environment to prevent page or column breaking between or inside them.

Comment: @Martin Thanks! But shouldn't you last comment be an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK columns are handled like different pages and so `\nopagebreak` should do what you want.

However, could simply wrap the paragraphs into `\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}` ... `\end{minipage}` to prevent page or column breaking between or inside them. This should work fine as long you don't have footnotes in the paragraphs which would be placed at the bottom of the `minipage`.